# Calling stored procedure with temporary table inside transactions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a javascript stored procedure which creates a temporary table inside it using the CTAS syntax to hold some temporary results during computation. I want to be able to call this stored procedure inside a transaction.
Is this not allowed?

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_proc()
RETURNS BOOLEAN NOT NULL 
LANGUAGE javascript 
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
    ...
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
        {sqlText: "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table..."}
        );
    var rs = stmt.execute();
    ...
$$;

BEGIN;
...
CALL my_stored_proc();
...
COMMIT;
```

I tried to wrap this stored proc with a transaction but it commits as soon as the stored proc completes, I want to be able to rollback the statements if there is an error thrown by the stored proc during execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that DDL statements (CREATE TABLE, etc.) cause an implicit COMMIT. Such statements should not be used inside a stored procedure if the procedure will be called inside a transaction.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#transaction-management